# is it possible to load a routers firmware into a vmware (or similar) virtual machine to test before loading it to the actual hardware?

Tags: firmware

I want to load some router firmware onto a virtual machine to run some testing/analysis without actually putting it on the router hardware. Is this possible and how would I go about doing it? Thanks :)

edit: it would be various routers and firmwares I'm looking more for a general idea of the process.

Comment: This obviously depends on what router hardware and firmware you are actually inquiring about. Please add this detail.

Comment: This is *extremely* hardware dependent. We will need specific hardware models you're looking for.

Comment: You need an emulator for the same hardware. If the router firmware is x86-based (say a Linux distro) then odds are it'll be fine in VMWare. Otherwise, you need a specific emulator for the specific router - there is no universal process.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Cisco routers, you may have success using [GNS3](http://www.gns3.net).

Really, Dynamips is the program that does the emulation, but GNS3 is a nice front end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If your router is a stock x86 router platform without special hardware, or something capable. Example: Mikrotik Router OS / Router OS based routers. Because this is what VmWare simulates.